# What exactly is returned in a Scala Future?

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and am working on an application using akka and futures

I have a class(C) that processes a future and returns a List(L) of objects type X. X has a field y and it is this field I am interesed in. (Note: L was previously converted from a ListBuffer type).

In the Main Class that calls C the code to process the result is:

Snippet A:

```
result1.onComplete {
    result =>
       result.foreach(f = (o: List[X]) => {
       o.foreach(f = (o: x) => {
         println(X.y)
       })
      })
  }
```

I can also use this code:

Snippet B:

```
result1 onSuccess{
  case result => 
  result.foreach(f = (o: X) => {
    println(o.y)
  })
}
```

Obviously, as OnSuccess is deprecated  the first form may be preferred. The second form (Snippet B) I can understand, but I am baffled as to why, when using onComplete, I have to use nested 'foreach' to get to the same result. If anyone can help as I dont yet have a clear conception of what 'result' (Try[T] => U) ??? actually is. Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: Could you please clarify your question.

Comment: My question  boils down to: What is the fundamental difference between onComplete and onSuccess methods that requires the difference in code given above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look to the `Future.onComplete` [*scaladoc*](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#onComplete[U](f:scala.util.Try[T]=%3EU)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):Unit), you will see that it receives a function from `Try[T]`, *(where T is the **type** of your future)*, to `Unit`.

> "When this future is completed, either through an exception, or a value, apply the provided function".
>   "Note that the returned value of f will be discarded".

The **Try** is there to catch **failures** on the *asynchronous computation* - that's why you need the two `foreach`, the first one is to extract the `Successful` **List** from the `Try`, and the second one is to extract each element `O` from the **List**.
You didn't need two in the case of `onSuccess` because, as the name says that *callback* would only be called if the **Future** completed successfully.

However, note that doing a `foreach` on a `Try` is a bad idea, since you are not handling the failure, also the code become hard to read - try this instead.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}

case class Result(data: Int)

val process: Future[List[Result]] =
  Future.successful(List(Result(data = 5), Result(data = 3)))

process.onComplete {
  case Success(results) =>
    for (result <- results) {
      println(result.data)
    }
  case Failure(ex) =>
    println(s"Error: ${ex.getMessage}")
}
```